# WFS in PostGIS OGR FDW results in "ERROR 1: No schema information loaded."

Tags: postgis, gdal, wfs, ogr, fdw

I am trying to add the WFS data of a german state to PostGIS using the [PostgreSQL OGR Foreign Data Wrapper](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-ogr-fdw):

```
CREATE SERVER server_mv
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER ogr_fdw
OPTIONS (
  datasource 'WFS:https://www.geodaten-mv.de/dienste/inspire_cp_alkis_download?VERSION=1.1.0',
  format 'WFS',
  config_options 'OGR_WFS_PAGE_SIZE=30000'
);

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA ogr_all
FROM SERVER server_mv
INTO public;
```

This results in an error: `ERROR 1: No schema information loaded.`

Answer (score 3):

The error messages comes from GDAL/OGR's [`NAS` driver](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/0cd1a79d062bb18208e16b6f32b37c57c1e04d56/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/nas/ogrnasdatasource.cpp#L135) and means that it could not find a (`GFS`) schema that describes the data.

In my case I did not want the data to be loaded using `NAS` but as standard `WFS`. So the solution was to blacklist the `NAS` driver for GDAL/OGR using the `OGR_SKIP` config option.

```
CREATE SERVER server_mv
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER ogr_fdw
OPTIONS (
  datasource 'WFS:https://www.geodaten-mv.de/dienste/inspire_cp_alkis_download?VERSION=1.1.0',
  format 'WFS',
  config_options 'OGR_WFS_PAGE_SIZE=30000 OGR_SKIP=NAS'
);
```

Comment: `OGR_WFS_PAGE_SIZE` is for WFS 2.0, but you are using WFS 1.1.0.

Comment: Oh thank you, that was a relic of another issue!

Comment: No actually https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/wfs.html#paging-with-wfs-1-0-or-1-1 disagrees with you

Comment: It's moot, you can use the flag, but if you're calling a WFS 1.n service there's a good chance it won't have any effect because those standards don't support paging.

Comment: "servers may support it as an vendor specific option also with WFS 1.0.0 and 1.1.0" implies a reasonable chance that a server *might* support it. Does it hurt to enable it?

Comment: No Harm, just may not give the results you are expecting, so just a case of be aware.  In your case however there is no issue because the `https://www.geodaten-mv.de/dienste/inspire_cp_alkis_download` service only supports WFS 2.

Comment: Much appreciated! Funnily enough their Capabilities also suggest it does not support pagination at all :}