# Intersect between PostGIS layer and ArcGIS/GeoServer service using ST_Intersection spatial SQL in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, arcgis-server, intersection, map-service

Is it possible to make intersection - ST_Intersection (or other spatial operations) on-the-fly between PostGIS polygon layer stored in local/cloud PostGIS DB and ArcGIS Map Service polygon layer (with the same CRS) using ST_Intersects spatial SQL or maybe some other method? Without the need of manually downloading the dataset from the map service (if even allowed) and importing it to PostGIS and maintainig it? To somehow call the service from PostGIS directly and make the intersection with other postgis layers and output result all within PostGIS?

Is this possible with either of these map services?

ArcGIS Map Sevice   (...arcgis/rest/services/SomeService/SomeLayer/MapServer...)

ArcGIS Map Service WMS (...arcgis/services/SomeService/SomeLayer/MapServer/WMSServer...)

ArcGIS Map Service WFS (...arcgis/services/SomeService/SomeLayer/MapServer/WFSServer...)

GeoServer WMS service (../geoserver/SomeWorkspace/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=SomeLayer...)

GeoServer WFS Service (.../geoserver/SomeWorkspace/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SomeLayer...)

Comment: No, you'd have to download it manually or with scripting. In the case of a WFS it wouldnt be too bad. Python get request, download to geojson, use ogr2ogr to import into postgres

Comment: ogr2ogr might even be able to take the endpoint and import to postgres in 1 command

Comment: This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460378/wfs-in-postgis-ogr-fdw-results-in-error-1-no-schema-information-loaded) shows how to use `ogr_fdw` directly in Postgis (beware that WFS server limits on number of returned features still applies)

Comment: @JGH nice find, I've never seen this. For larger endpoints it would still be better to download it to access all features